# Vacuum Seal Meats with Bones that could be sharp

Tags: sous-vide, vacuum

I am interested in vacuum sealing things like bone in pork chops and t-bone steaks for sous vide cooking. Is there a technique to keep the bones from puncturing the bags?

Comment: Aren't there heavy(er) duty bags that you can use ? if not wrap the bones ends like moscafj answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the bone ends with a layer of foil, plastic wrap...or even folded paper towel. Then seal.

Comment: I wouldn't use paper, you will get some paper taste in your food.

Comment: @GdD I don't have a chamber vacuum, just your standard, counter top, consumer FoodSaver brand.  So I frequently place a folded paper towel at the top of the bag to prevent moisture from being sucked into my machine.  The paper gets sealed inside.  I've also used it to pad the bone ends as I suggested above.  The paper comes right out when I open the bag, and I've never noticed off flavors.

Answer (score 1):

I usually cut off excess fat & use it to cover the sharp bone ends.

Answer (score 0):

I first wrap in paper towel then put that into a regular freezer bag. Squeeze out all the air so it lays flat. Then I vac seal. Works perfectly.